# Obtain saved_model.pb location for specific GCMLE model from within jupyter notebook

Tags: python, google-cloud-ml

I have a GCMLE model deployed as a `model` for GCMLE prediction service.  In the GCP console UI I can navigate to the model name -> version and then I can view the `Model location` (ie gs://..../) which specifies the location of my `saved_model.pb` file. Is there any way to dynamically obtain this "model location" within a jupyter notebook/python script? I would like to be able to then use this model location to download the `saved_model.pb` locally so that I can load the model into a local session for debugging purposes on specific inference tasks.  Currently, I can do all of this manually, but I'd like to be able to quickly flip between model versions without needing to manually track/download the `saved_model.pb` files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issuing a GET request [(docs)](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects.models.versions/get) against your version resource will return a [Version](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/reference/rest/v1/projects.models.versions#Version) object that has the `deploymentUri` field you are looking for. You can use any library for issuing HTTP request in your language of choice, although you do need to send an authorization token in the headers.

Here's an example in Python:

```
import requests
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

token = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default().get_access_token().access_token
api = 'https://ml.googleapis.com/v1/projects/MYPROJECT/models/MYMODEL/versions/MYVERSION'
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token }    
response = requests.get(api, headers=headers)
print response.json()['deploymentUri']
```